# Reload page in Node.js using Express and EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to reload the browser page when the underlying data model changes:

```
var request = require('request');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

var requests;

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        requests: requests
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

...and later when requests data model changes:

```
request.get('localhost:3000/', function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

but my browser page doesn't refresh unless I manually tap the refresh button with my mouse. What am I missing?

**EDIT**: Here is my `index.ejs` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<ul>
    <% requests.forEach(function(match) { %>
        <form action="/acceptRequest" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
            <input type="text" name="id" value="<%= match.id %>">
            <input type="text" name="fighter1" value="<%= match.fighter1 %>"> vs.
            <input type="text" name="fighter2" value="<%= match.fighter2 %>"> on
            <input type="text" name="fightdate" value="<%= match.date %>"> in
            <input type="text" name="rounds" value="">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <br>
        <% }); %>
</ul>

</html>
```

Comment: What code are you running in the browser that you expect to cause a refresh.  Your `request.get()` requests a page, but doesn't do anything with the contents.  You can just issues a `window.reload()` if you want the browser to just reload the current page.  Or you can fetch the updated contents with Ajax and then insert the content into the DOM yourself.

Comment: @jfriend00 added my ejs code

Comment: I still don't understand what action in the web page you want to trigger a reload from?  That's the one part of your question you have not made clear.  Is it a form post to `/acceptRequest`?  Or an Ajax call somewhere?  Or something else?

Comment: nodemon module is the best fit to do this type of task

Answer (score 2):

There is a thing called `HTTP Referer`: It is an HTTP header field that identifies the address of the page that linked to the resource being requested.

If you want to refresh a page, after the user sends a request that changes something, just redirect to the referer.

```
app.get('/someRequest', function(request, response) {

    // some things changed here.
    response.redirect(request.get('referer'));
});
```

Comment: but I need to reload outside of the `app.get` so I don't have access to `response`.

Comment: @AdamJohns, do you want to reload the `localhost:3000/` ?

Comment: @AdamJohns : Any progress? How did you solve? My requirement is same as yours :(

Comment: This does not work

Answer (score 2):

To reload the html page:

```
<script>
location.reload(true/false);
</script>
```

Also, you want to restart the server  whenever a change is made use nodemon instead of nodejs to run your server.

To install nodemon:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

To run the server(app.js is the main server file)

```
nodemon apps.js
```

Nodemon looks for the changes and restarts the server whenever found.

Comment: This "location.reload(true/false);" is so bad, please don't do this.

Comment: @Undefined i dont want a file system menu, so ive used `Menu.setApplicationMenu(null)`, but now i have no way of reloading the page for the main window? i tried `globalShortcut.register('Ctrl+R', ()=>{ window.location.reload() })` but this obvs doesnt work. is there something else i can do?