# How to force a full page reload after a redirect to the same modified page?

Tags: express, redirect, reload, server-side

I have quite a problem with `Express` (I'm using `Cloud Firestore`), and haven't found any solutions on SO (even if [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352241/reload-a-page-after-res-redirectback-in-route) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002477/reload-page-in-node-js-using-express-and-ejs) seem to discuss my problem)

Below a simple `route`
(everything is `server-side`):

```
// This route is accessible from www.site.com/123/options
router.post('/add', async (req, res, next) => {

  ...

  // 'add' modifies a document in DB and works.

  add(id, stuffToAdd)

  // Afterwards, I want to redirect to www.site.com/123/options/
  // But I need to `CTRL+R` to see new data one the page

  res.header(
    'Cache-Control',
    'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0'
  )
  res.redirect(`back`)
})
```

I've tried many things:

- add `301`, `302`, `304`, `307` status to `res.redirect` (no success)
- add a `?v=something` at the end of URL to bypass `cache` (no success)
- modify `headers` like above (no success)...

Do you have any clue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

cant you just force reload on client side?

jQuery ajax
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/add",
    type: "POST"
}).done( () => {
    location.reload();
})
```

Or ES6 function fetch
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

```
fetch('/test', {
    method: "POST"
 })
.then(response => (
    location.reload()
));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd prefer to do it server-side (2 benefits: learning why it is not working, keep it server-side and do not use JQuery :-p).

Comment: insteed of jQuery You can use ES6 Fetch function. Ofc if You wont find server side answer